# Find the Asymptotes of the function $f(x)=3^x / (3^x+1)$

Tags: limits

Find the Asymptotes of the function $f(x)=3^x / (3^x+1)$

No way for Vertical asymptotes since the denominator can not be zero

Also, there is no slant asymptote since we will have horizontal asymptotes ( this is the only reason I have )

we are left with horizontal asymptote, there are two : I found one but I could not find the other

I took the limit as x approches $infinite$, sloving it using $L'H Rule$

I got $y=1$ "V.A"  ,, and there is another one which is $y=0$ .

How to find it ?

Comment: Try $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: I did ! but I got y=1 ?

Comment: As $x \rightarrow -\infty,$ $e^{x} \rightarrow 0,$ so $f(x) \rightarrow \frac{0}{0+1} = 0,$ so $y = 0$ is the asymptote as $x \rightarrow -\infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common sense: In the first place, recall that $3^x\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$.  And if you don't recall that, look at this:
\begin{align}
3^0 & = 1 \\
3^{-1} & = 1/3 \\
3^{-2} & = 1/9 \\
& {}\ \ \vdots
\end{align}
every time $x$ gets one step closer to $-\infty$, then $3^x$ gets $1/3$ as big.  So it approaches $0$.

That gives us $\dfrac{3^x}{1+3^x}\to\dfrac 0 {1+0}$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Next recall that $3^x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.  That means the "$1$" in $\dfrac{3^x}{1+3^x}$ becomes negligible by comparison to the immense number $3^x$, so the whole thing approaches $1$.  Or if you like, do this:
$$
\frac{3^x}{1+3^x} = \frac{1}{\frac1{3^x}+1} \to \frac 1 {0+1} \text{ as }x\to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 6):

There are $2$ horizontal asymptotes: $y =0$ and $y = 1$ that correspond to $x \to -\infty$, and $x \to +\infty$. To see it clearer we write: $y = 1-\dfrac{1}{3^x+1}$

Comment: How did you put it in this form?

Comment: $y = \dfrac{(3^x+1)-1}{3^x+1} = 1-\dfrac{1}{3^x+1}$